# SVG is visibly clipped, but I still get scroll bars - Cropping SVG

Tags: html, browser, svg, rendering

If I have an SVG element that extends beyond the size of the SVG, I get scroll bars in my browser.  I want to stretch the SVG control to be the size of the visible region and I don't want elements that are partially visible to cause scroll bars to appear on the page.

I've distilled this down to a simple example.  Here's what I have in the body of my HTML document:

```
<svg width="200" height="200">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="clippath">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" />
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <g clip-path="url(#clippath)">
        <rect x="100" y="50" width="2000" height="50" style="stroke: red; stroke-width: 5; fill: lightblue" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

As you can see the SVG element is defined to be 200x200 and it is visibly clipped to 200x200.  However, when you open this in your browser you will see a scroll bar because the rectangle extends out past the end of the SVG element and off the page.

How do I get rid of the scroll bars?  Essentially I'd like to crop the SVG to the clip path.

Update: This seems to only be a problem in IE.  Firefox and Chrome render it the way I like it.

Comment: Have you tried setting it to "overflow:hidden"?

Comment: Bingo! `<svg overflow=hidden ...>`

Comment: Would you mind if I placed that answer below and you accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much the same as the CSS property, you should be able to use overflow:hidden;

As you noticed, in the case of `<svg>` it will be inline and shown as overflow=hidden.